# number sorting in java

Tags: java, regex, sorting, logic

Im having trouble figuring out a way to sort cetain numbers im trying to brain storm ways to sort, but thought the community has an answer already

What Im trying to sort are numbers like:

1. FA8Z-7406024-AB
2. DS7Z-6632394-D
3. AA8Z-6632394-S
4. SR3Z-15342-H
5. TR3Z-72B39842-S
6. TR3Z-7239842-S

The sorting method should go by the middle first, then the first number, then finally the last number

If i sort the list above, it should look like this:

1. SR3Z-15342-H
2. AA8Z-6632394-S
3. DS7Z-6632394-S
4. TR3Z-7239842-S
5. TR3Z-72B39842-S
6. FA8Z-7406024-AB

If the middle number has a letter in it, the letter should be ignored but it should be sorted after any numbers that resemble the number but without the letter (IE the TR3Z's).

Edit: fixed example

Comment: Create a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: and post the code after which if you have problems, specify them.

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Derrainga The example doesn't correspond to the description. If it needs to be sorted by middle number first then `FA8Z-7406024-AB` should be the second entry in output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the entried adhere to the same format, this should do with the exception that `FA8Z-7406024-AB` will be the second element in sorted array due to middle value based comparison:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = (s1, s2) -> {
    String[] tokens1 = s1.split("-");
    String[] tokens2 = s2.split("-");

    int number1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens1[1].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    int number2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens2[1].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));

    //Compare the numbers
    if(number1 - number2 == 0 && tokens1[1].length() == tokens2[1].length()){
        //Compare the Strings
        return tokens1[0].compareTo(tokens2[0]) == 0 ? tokens1[2].compareTo(tokens2[2]) : tokens1[0].compareTo(tokens2[0]); 
    }else if (tokens1[1].length() != tokens2[1].length()){
        return tokens1[1].length() - tokens2[1].length();
    }else{
        return number1 - number2;
    }
};
```

Here's an example:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("FA8Z-7406024-AB", "DS7Z-66329294-D", "AA8Z-66329294-S", "SR3Z-15342-H", "TR3Z-72B381942-S", "TR3Z-72381942-S");

Collections.sort(list, comparator);

System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Please provide enough explanation and do not encourage  answering questions that are not clear!